# windows command prompt shortcut

Tags: windows, command-prompt

I have just recently started using the Windows Command Prompt in order to do some python development. I was wondering if there's any way to create some sort of shortcut so that I can just type: "python program.py" rather than "C:\Python27\python.exe program.py"

Comment: The .py extension should be configured to run with the default Python, so you can simply run `program.py`. If you install 3.3 or later you'll get the py.exe launcher that adds shebang support to scripts, e.g. `#!python2` or `#!C:\Python27\python.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add "C:\Python27\" to your Windows PATH variable.

[Here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) is a web page that illustrates how to do this. (I did not write this webpage.)